# Changing the default JSON in Jersesy-Jackson

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I am building a RESTful service using Jersey (Jackson POJO mapping) and have some doubts...
Imagine a forum-like application where in the domain I have **Group** and **Question** POJO.

Group.java

```
class Group{
    int id;
    String name;
 //setter/getters
}
```

Question.java

```
class Question{
    int id;
    String title;
    String text;
  //setter/getters

}
```

As you can see I have no relationship defined between these two classes. What I'm trying to say Group doesn't have a

```
private Question[] questions;
```

When I call GET /rest/groups I get a perfect JSON:

```
{
   [
     {"id":1, "name":"Group name..." },
     {"id":2, "name":"Group name..." }

   ]
}
```

What Im trying to get when I aks for GET /rest/groups/12 is:

```
 {
   "group":{
       "id":12,
       "name":"Group 12"

    },
    "questions":[
           {"id":102, "title":"question title..." },
           {"id":201, "title":"question title..." }   
     ]

}
```

I was able to get something similar by defining a member variable in the Group class:

```
 private Question[] questions;
```

I am trying to keep clean my domain classes from HAS-A dependency since I'll be using Hibernate and will define the relation through annotations. 
The question is: 
what's the best and the most flexible way of formatting the JSON I want to return for resources that have HAS-A relationship with another one...

Comment: second json format is it question, questions or group, questions? assume it is a typo

Comment: sorry, it's a typo... It's just an example... Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build something like a `GroupResponse` object:

```
class GroupRespose {
  final Group question;
  final List<Question> questions;
}
```

And use this as your response object.  This will give you the format that you want (although given your question I suspect that you really wanted `final Group group` and it was a typo in the question).

Comment: Does this mean that the domain object I'll use for REST will be different or include more objects than the ORM ones: 1 table, 1 object, no weak association entity ? 
Ok, I guess I'll try combining your approach with Hibernate or MyBatis and see how it goes... Thanks

Comment: another thing... why final? and ain't we missing a constructor GroupResponse(Group group, Question[] questions)

Comment: `final` out of habit (all my objects are immutable).  And yes you're missing a constructor, and all the other bits of the object, but this is the bare bones of the class you need.

Comment: As for your first comment, if you want a 1:1 mapping of REST to ORM objects then they will need to have the same data and contain it in the same manner.  In your case this is not true, so you need some translation between your data model objects and your data transfer objects.  Personally I think that this is probably overkill for what you are doing, but if you want things as per your original question that's the way it has to be.

Comment: I have some doubts now that I started implementing my MyBatis layer where relations are maintained through Collection variable so it seems that my REST model (and your suggestion) will have to differ from my MyBatis model ...

Comment: I would suggest that you start with REST based on your model and see if that is suitable.  You are usually better off changing your JSON parsing at the receiving end than altering the model, or putting another layer in as per my answer, if at all possible.